# Im using touch to create a file in a folder on my desktop... Right when I tried this it says command not found

Tags: linux, shell, unix, touch

At first I had

```
touch $NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT
```

then I changed it to

```
PATH="Logs/"
touch $PATH$NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT
```

The file is created correctly in the folder, however only echos are being printed in there because says commands are not found like grep, awk, and others.

EDIT: The folder is already created on my desktop

Thanks 
Alan

Comment: This is _exactly_ why you shouldn't use uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` is an environment variable that specifies where executables are located and is used by your shell to look for commands executables (grep, awk, ...). You should not override it in your script.

Try:

```
MYPATH="Logs/"
touch $MYPATH$NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT
```

To understand what `PATH` is open a shell and type `echo $PATH`. You will see it contains the directories where your commands executables are.

Comment: Now I get an error awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file '-v' for reading <No such file or directory>..... Should I be doing something with the **/** in logs?

Comment: Hard to say with the little information we have about the rest of you script. If `touch $MYPATH$NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT` worked correctly then the error is probably somewhere else. Did you update `$PATH` to `$MYPATH` everywhere? Try to debug your script and if the problem persists consider posting a new question.

Comment: Got it.. Missing a -v for when I added MYPATH="$MYPATH" to awk.. Thanks for your help